# Spawning a Robot in Gazebo using Python Launch File

Tags: ros, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is something I struggled with for a few hours today and I wanted to post this for posterity. If you have a URDF file and want to launch Gazebo with the robot spawned then this will get you there:

```
launch_gazebo_arg = IncludeLaunchDescription(
 PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([get_package_share_directory('ros_ign_gazebo'), '/launch', '/ign_gazebo.launch.py']),
 launch_arguments={
  'ign_args' : #Add path to World File if so desired
 }.items(),
)

spawn_robot_arg = Node(
 package='ros_ign_gazebo',
 executable='create',
 output='screen',
 arguments=["-file", "<path_to_urdf>/robot.urdf"]
)

return LaunchDescription([
 launch_gazebo_arg,
 spawn_robot_arg
])
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413178/spawning-a-robot-in-gazebo-using-python-launch-file/) by [ROS_Engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/139551/ros_engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution to spawning a robot from a URDF file into a Gazebo instance provided above. Hope it helped.

---

Originally posted by [ROS_Engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/139551/ros_engineer/) with karma: 16 on 2023-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0